# MVC3 display date + short time without format string

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, culture, datetime-format

In MVC you can do

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt}"]
```

This would translate to

> 10/12/2011 1:30 PM

Which is correct for a en-US user

But lets say a Swedish user visits the site (sv-SE)

Then I want

> 2011-10-12 13:30

so i cant use format string.. if i remove format attribute from the model I'll get

10/12/2011 1:30:20 PM for en-US
and
2011-10-12 13:30:20 for sv-SE

How can I get the correct format without seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `g` format specifier, which is the "General date short time" format specifier, which happens to be the one you are looking for.

Like this:

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:g}")]
 // Displays 2011-10-12 11:40 for sv-SE
 // Displays 10/12/2011 11:40 AM for en-US
```

Full docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: Now I have problems with the DisplayFormat attribute and custom editor, but your solution will probably work once I get that to work. thanks!